# I'm sending a JSON Body from Postman to hit Apex, but I'm getting a deserializing error

Tags: apex, apexrest, postman

I'm using below payload from postman and trying to hit an Apex class.

```json
{
    "First_Name__c": "elon",
    "Last_Name__c": "musk",
    "Email__c": "elon.musk@gmail.com",
    "Phone__c": 1233245645
}
```

I'm getting the below error.

> [{"message": "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: First_Name__c [line:2, column:29]",
> "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
> }]

My Apex code is of HTTPpost method with 4 parameters, with one parameter as this JSON. The first three parameters are sent as query parameters. if first three are null and JSON is sent. it will deserialize and add the record. (For businesss purpose i changed the object name.) iF first three parametrs have data. json paramter will be null

```java
@HttpPost
updterecord(String id, String email, String phone, String Jsonuser){
       Account AccountRecord = 
           (Account)JSON.deserialize(Jsonuser, 
               Account.class);
}
insert AccountRecord;
```

Comment: Parameters are mismatching in the call and webservice. Your webservice doesn't have any parameters by the name FirstName or LastName.

Comment: I've edited your question to have better formatting (you should look through [the help page on formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)), but I've left the obvious error of your DML appearing _outside of your method_ in case that's also an issue in your actual code.

Comment: There's definitely a couple of things to look at here. Do you really have custom fields for First and Last Name, Email and Phone on the Account object? Also, you have a trailing comma after the Phone attribute so this is a malformed JSON string.

Comment: the first three parameters are sent as query params, the fourth one is json. if first three are null, im planning to use the json and isnert the record.

Answer (score 2):

As Mahmood says in their comment, this is because the parameters of your method do not match the data structure of your JSON.

From [the documentation on Apex REST Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm)

> If the Apex method has no parameters, Apex REST copies the HTTP request body into the RestRequest.requestBody property. If the method has parameters, then Apex REST attempts to deserialize the data into those parameters and the data won't be deserialized into the RestRequest.requestBody property.

So if you're going to declare parameters for your method, your JSON needs to use the same structure.

Through some brief testing, you cannot do partial deserialization, so JSON like

```json
{
    "id ":"123",
    "email":"123@abc.com",
    "phone":"123-456-7890",
    "jsonuser":{
        "First_Name__c": "some",
        "Last_Name__c": "person",
        "Email__c": "some.person@gmail.com",
        "Phone__c": 1233245645,
    }
}
```

will not work, with the following signature

```java
@HttpPost
updterecord(String id, String email, String phone, String Jsonuser){
```

because Salesforce cannot just take the data inside of "jsonuser" and shove it into a string.

Your best bet here is probably to remove the parameters from your method signature, and then fetch the JSON from `RestRequest.requestBody`